# Unable to create subsite with team site template in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am working on sharepoint 2013.I have a created a site collection using sharepoint central administration. I have the admin access to the site collection and its subsite features.When i am trying to create a subsite under that site collection (where i selected the Team Site template), then i got an error message saying that **The URL SitePages/Home.aspx is invalid. It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web**.When i tried with other templates the subsite was successfully created.
[image]
Anybody have any idea on this issue?Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this post when attempting to resolve this issue for myself and thought I'd share my "lesson learned".

Our site collection is using a design package for branding. We'd work on changes for the design package in a development area and when we were ready to move the changes to our production site, we would deactivate the existing design package in the Solutions gallery, delete, and import the new design package.

TREMENDOUS mistake.

Deactivating the design package created the exact issue described by the original poster.  In the ULS logs, we would see the following:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Parameter '@tp_Author' was supplied multiple times.     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataRead...

To resolve this issue we had to deactivate, rename, and reactivate the existing design package in the Solutions gallery. We then had to restore the previous version(s) of the design package from the Site Collection recycle bin and reactivate. Finally, we ran the following PowerShell script:

```
if((get-pssnapin ‘microsoft.sharepoint.powershell’ -ea 0) -eq $null){add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell}
cls

# Change $siteUrl to the site collection you want to update
$siteUrl = ‘http://YourSiteCollectionUrlHere’

$site = get-spsite $siteUrl

if((get-spfeature -identity Fields -site $site) -eq $null)
{
   Enable-SPFeature -Identity Fields -url $site.url
}
else
{
   Disable-SPFeature -Identity Fields -url $site.url -force
   Enable-SPFeature -Identity Fields -url $site.url
}

$site.dispose()

write-host “Done”
```

Thanks to Google and the article at the following URL for helping us to finally resolve this issue:

https://guidesharepoint.wordpress.com/2015/05/07/using-sharepoint-2013-design-package-do-not-deactivate-packages-in-solution-gallery-never/